# Rewrite rule with time conditions in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is my first post on stackoverflow, as usually I managed to find an answer in the existing discussions, this time I did not :-)

I need to create temporary url redirections based on day/time conditions for a few of my site pages. My site is hosted on OVH (Apache 2.4, mutualized) and I used Wordpress as CMS (4.9.1).

I have read the Apache documentation about mod_rewrite, as well browsed different sources to do some trial/error testings, did not manage to get a piece of code to work in my `.htaccess` file (root www).

I want to achieve the following: URL1 (`https://www.mysite.co/url1`) should be redirected to URL2 (`https://www.mysite.co/url2`) from Monday 5pm till Thursday 5pm. Then (outside this time window), redirection does not happen.

I tried to implement some simple rewrite rules to already get URL1 to be redirected to URL2 when time > given date/hour, but did not work - see codes I tried:

- **Code 1:**

/# Redirect URL1 to URL2 when TIME > Nov 30 2017, 6:15pm

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteRule ^URL1$ /URL2? [L,R=301]
```

**- Code 2:**

/# Redirect URL1 to URL2 when TIME > Nov 30 2017, 6:15pm

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /URL1.*
RewriteRule (.*) /URL2 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

I know I am doing sthg wrong, but can't figure out what/where on my own, so I'd be thankful if someone could help me out solve this silly issue!

Am attaching a copy of my [`.htaccess`](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rAqITc_D3IhRIPwssuYes0PBIbr2sacc) in case helpful/anything to check there (I have removed all lines of codes referring to this matter).

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT (12/05/17) - Code 1 & 2 with full URLs:**

**- Code 1**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteRule ^commande-lundi$ /desole? [L,R=301]
```

With « full » URLs would be :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteRule ^https://mysite.co/commande-lundi$ /https://mysite.co/desole? [L,R=301]
```

**- Code 2**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /commande-lundi.*
RewriteRule (.*) /desole [L,R=302,QSA]
```

With full URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}%{TIME_HOUR}%{TIME_MIN} >201711301815
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /https://mysite.co/commande-lundi.*
RewriteRule (.*) /https://mysite.co/desole [L,R=302,QSA]
```

Comment: Please try this may help you ?

https://harrybailey.com/2015/08/htaccess-redirects-based-on-date-and-time/

Comment: Your Code1 seems fine. Does it redirect when you remove RewriteCond?

Comment: @DusanBajic: unfortunately, no it doesnt when I remove the RewriteCond... it is very strange I must say as I tried a bunch of codes, even the most simple ones, and no rules worked. Yet, the rule for https and www redirections do work... so there must be a "conflict" or sthg somewhere in my .htaccess file... what think?

Comment: @PardeepPathania: I used the guidance from Harry B. to work out my code initially... I wished it was as simple as what's in there for me ;-)

Comment: Can you show **exactly** how your RewriteRule looks (just replace your domain name with `example.com`)

Comment: uh, please edit your question, it will be more readable :)

Comment: Jeez... Indeed... working on it... sorry not sure how to do so! will repost in few minutes!!

Comment: @DusanBajic: I have edited my initial post with the full URL/code in it... ;-)

Comment: 1) RewriteRule pattern should not contain scheme or hostname, only path (without the leading `/` if used in `.htaccess`)

Comment: 2) While you are troubleshooting, place your rules at the top of .htaccess to make sure they are not influenced by previous rules (although it doesn't look so)

Comment: @DusanBajic indeed... In all honesty I only used the /commande-lundi and /desole path in my codes, never the full path... I have tried even simpler codes to see if I was able to make some redirections/rewrite rules work, and  none worked, so I start to think there is sthg conflicting with my htacess file... Any idea what that could be / where (which file/setting) I should investigate on? Meantime, I'll try what you just suggested...

Comment: Also, test without RewriteCond first, we need to make your rule work, then you can include the condition

Comment: I just tried Code 1 at top of my .htaccess and without the RewriteCond (ie line 1: RewriteEngine On, followed by line 2: RewriteRule ^commande-mercredi$ /desole? [L,R=301]). Not working... I even tried a new htaccess file with no other line of code (excl. the #BEGIN WordPress (...) #END WordPress).

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but, if you remove .htaccess, does your http->https redirection still work?